# Different sorting of Java CLASSPATH in install4j launcher using Scan directory option on different system environments

Tags: classpath, install4j

We have a strange behaviour calling a java application using an install4j launcher (install4J R5.0.11) on different environments. The launcher uses the scan directory option (for the jar files) to set the CLASSPATH before starting the main class. The CLASSPATH is logged for debugging in our application.

On system 1 the entries of the CLASSPATH are sorted ascending by filename.

On sytem 2 the entries are sorted descending.

This leads to an exception on system 2, because of a wrong order of two jars.

Does the "Scan directory option" take into account system settings (eg. sorting)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on classpath sorting with the scan directory entries, the behavior is system-specific.